# switching between divs and iframes

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, html, iframe

I have a main viewing area that I want to be switchable from a menu by clicking on a menu item.

In this main viewing area I want to have the flexibility of being able to switch between a `div` and `iframe`. I know how to change them separately.

My question is how can I do this and what is the best way to do this? I'm not sure how to support both divs and iframes in a single viewing area and what would be the best way to do this.

I'm using JQuery and bootstrap currently but I'm open to suggestions if they are needed.

Comment: What have you tried ? switching can be done adding a class to show / hide the items respectively, depending on the item that was clicked.

Comment: @DavidStrada I'm new to javascript but with your suggestion, showing/hiding won't the hidden viewing page still be loaded in the browser? This is good and bad i guess. So I have a main controller div, that handles visibility of only one instance at a time inside of it and I inject divs or iframes into this main controller div when they need to be loaded?

Comment: Check the examples of toggle here [link](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) if you are using jQuery ( i'm assuming this ).

Comment: @DavidStrada awesome thanks! I'm using JQuery and this helps